# Getting "{{component}} refers to to a value, but is being used as a type" error when attemping to identify an argument that refers to a Vue Component

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a function that takes as a parameter a Vue Component.

**dothings.ts**

```
import App from 'src/app';

export default class DoThings {
  public static fetch(liveApp: App) {
    liveApp.updateMe = 'updated';
  }
}
```

I would like to pass the App component into the `fetch` function so I can manipulate its state as a part of the function. The App component looks like this:

**app.vue**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import DoThings from 'dothings';


export default Vue.extend({
  data() {
    return {
      updateMe: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetch() {
      DoThings.fetch(this);
    }
  },
});
```

My attempts to refer to the "App" component, exported by `app.vue`, are failing with the error:

```
  TS2749: 'App' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.
```

with a pointer to the line `public static fetch....`

**What is the proper way to indicate the Type I am expecting to be passed into a function is an exported Vue component?**

Particularly, I'm not clear how Typescript can know that Vue maps all values on its `data()` method returned object to properties of the Vue component itself. Same for methods. I tried using just `Vue.Component` as the type, but obviously that threw errors about things like `updateMe` not existing on the type `Vue.Component`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use the typescript `typeof` operator.

```
import App from 'src/app';

export default class DoThings {
  public static fetch(liveApp: typeof App) {
    liveApp.updateMe = 'updated';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, solved the similar kind of problem with your solution.